# Android device internal storage full path

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making AR video playback app.
I want to play video from device storage instead of include it in the app.
In the path field in video texture I should write the path of the internal storage.
I wrote "/storage"emulated/0/Demo.mp4" (video's name is Demo)
It works on the testing device, but when I try running the app on other device it does not work because the path differs (internal path is :/storage/sdcard0)
What is the path should I wrote in the video texture to ensure running the app whatever the device is?

Comment: How are your end users going to get this video? Because if you still intend to package and download from google play you might need to go down the expansion pack route.

Comment: Or is it they can play a video of their choice?

Comment: this app is not for public users, it is for a company with limmited and well known users, so the video must be in the device and have a specified name, and located in a specified location. 
the problem I face as mentioned above is the difference in the internal storage path between devices, and I dont know what path should I write in the path field in video texture! @weston

Comment: what about [Application.temporaryCachePath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-temporaryCachePath.html)  or [Application.dataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)?

Comment: those point to the app assets, but they could not find an external data path!
that's how I understood them!! 
I dont know if I understood correctly
@JeanLuc

Answer (score 0):

To find locations on internal storage for your app, use `getFilesDir()`, called on any Context (such as your Activity, to get a File object.

To get a location on external storage unique for your app, use `getExternalFilesDir()`, called on any Context (such as your Activity, to get a File object.

To get a standard location on external storage for common types of files (e.g., movies), use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on Environment.

To get the root of external storage, use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` on Environment. This, however, is considered sloppy programming nowadays, as it encourages developers to just put files in random locations.

Comment: Do you know where I should write this code in Unity android project.
what should I write In the path field in video texture inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding things is not the best way but you could check if the video exists in

```
 /sdcard
 /mnt/sdcard
 /storage/sdcard0
 /storage/emulated/0
 /storage/emulated/legacyode
```

at least those are the most common places for android devices.
Then set the patch programatically instead of using the inspector

Comment: How to set the path programatically?

Comment: @Mohamad if you found the file using If's you should be abled to acess the property of the script wich holds the video path... it would be helpful if you could provide some screenshots!